# PHP - assign variable to dynamic list object

Tags: php, magento

I have a piece of PHP code (in a Magento installation) which produces a list of URLs, I need to put a variable with each of these, for example the first URL could be assigned to `$curGBP`, the second to `$curEUR`,and so on... I've managed to produce what the variable name needs to be so it's just putting the final part of the jigsaw together.

I currently have this code:

```
<?php foreach ($this->getCurrencies() as $_code => $_name): ?>
<?php echo $this->getSwitchCurrencyUrl($_code) ?>
<?php echo "\$cur"?><?php echo $_code ?><br />
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Which produces this output:

```
../GBP/uenc/SESSIONID/ $curGBP  
../EUR/uenc/SESSIONID/ $curEUR
../USD/uenc/SESSIONID/ $curUSD
../AED/uenc/SESSIONID/ $curAED
```

What do I need to add to the foreach section to assign the URL to a variable?

**Note:** SESSIONID is a long string which I've replaced in this example for neatness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php foreach ($this->getCurrencies() as $_code => $_name): ?>
<?php ${"cur$_code"} = $this->getSwitchCurrencyUrl($_code) ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

That should assign the currency url to the variable names you want to.

For more information if you don´t know how it works, have a look to the variable variables:
http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

Comment: I forgot to add the "cur" prefix but already modified it on the answer. Anyway the hard part is to find out that variable variables exists xD I learned about them a while after I started programming php